# ImportError: No module named qgis.core

Tags: pyqgis, ubuntu

I am on Ubuntu 13.04. I get the following error message -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "analyse.py", line 1, in <module>
        from log import shelve
      File "/home/shubham/SMART/TaxiData/log.py", line 27, in <module>
        from demo import *
      File "/home/shubham/SMART/zones/demo.py", line 5, in <module>
        from qgis.core import *
    ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

Actually, everything was working fine till today morning. I guess this might be due to a package update.

The qgis version I am using is 1.8.0-2~raring1. The remote repository is http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not the first with that problem, see 
["Ubuntu 13.04 and QGIS" at qgismalaysia.blogspot.de](http://qgismalaysia.blogspot.de/2013/04/ubuntu-1304-and-qgis.html)

There have been some python API changes, which have not been solved for QGIS Lisboa. And awaiting QGIS 2.0, I'm afraid they may not be solved.

(That's why I like my Windows installation: No automatic updates spoiling the running application)

You can try the repository at `http://qgis.org/debian raring main` after deleting your broken installation, or set up a virtual box with a separated Ubuntu 12.04, like I did.